# tutorial for yii with openssl

Tags: php, yii, openssl

I have a Yii website which I want to integrate with openssl. I am looking for a tutorial or steps to do so. I am amateur as far as security part is concert. Can anyone one give links to the good tutorial or can explain steps to integrate Yii with openssl. I tried to search but could not find a well explained one.

Comment: In what way do you wish to integrate with OpenSSL? Do you want to deploy a website to an `https:` address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am following this tutorial. I have Apache installed on Linux. Ideally it does not have anything to do with Yii or PHP framework. Therefore follow the steps and simply replace all the http in the project with https.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/install-apache2-ssl/

However you can force ssl by adding following lines to .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. It was the one I was looking for...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Apache webserver, you can use this guide

http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm